# How can i use the escape key to switch between main menu view mode and playing view mode and move the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is when i click the escape key once in any time and place in the game it will move the camera to the main menu view meaning very close to the player and then everything will be idle not freezing. and the main menu will be show. Another click on the escape key will move the camera back up and behind the player i think this the right position when in playing view. Not sure but i think when in playing view mode the camera should some behind and above the player.

Now for now what i did is when running the game it's in the main menu view ( i din't create yet a main menu ). I also did that when i click the escape key it's freezing the game and another click continue the game by using Time.timeScale and switching between 0 and 1.

But Time.timeScale freeze the game i want to be in idle when it's in the main menu.
And i'm not sure how to make the camera move fly smooth each time switching between the view modes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    int count = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                count = 0;
            }
            // to make here a switching mode between
            //playing screen and pause/main menu screen.
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the main menu view

[image: Main menu view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `Animator` component to make the move of your `Camera`. In that Animator put the Update Mode to "Unscaled Time". That way it keeps working when your timescale is 0.